# Counting number of points in lower left quadrant?

Tags: algorithm, fenwick-tree

I am having trouble understanding a [solution](http://www.usaco.org/current/data/sol_median.html) to an algorithmic [problem](http://www.usaco.org/index.php?page=viewproblem2&cpid=91)

In particular, I don't understand how or why this part of the code

```
s += a[i];
total += query(s);
update(s);
```

allows you to compute the total number of points in the lower left quadrant of each point.

Could someone please elaborate?

Comment: Link presents some solution, but where a problem is??

Comment: Please add the relevant parts of the problem statement and solution here, so that your question is self-contained even without the external website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an analogue for the plane problem, consider this:

1. For a point (a, b) to lie in the lower left quadrant of (x, y), a <
   x & b < y; thus, points of the form (i, P[i]) lie in the lower left quadrant
   of (j, P[j]) iff i < j and P[i] < P[j]
2. When iterating in ascending order, all points that were considered earlier lie on the left compared to the current (i, P[i])
3. So one only has to locate all P[j]s less that P[i] that have been considered until now

*current point refers to the point in consideration in the current iteration of the for loop that you quoted ie, (i, P[i])

Let's define another array, C[s]:

```
C[s] = Number of Prefix Sums of array A[1..(i - 1)] that amount to s
```

So the solution to #3 becomes the sum ... C[-2] + C[-1] + C[0] + C[1] + C[2] ... C[P[i] - 1], ie prefix sum of C[P[i]]

Use the BIT to store the prefix sum of C, thus defining query(s) as:

```
query(s) = Number of Prefix Sums of array A[1..(i - 1)] that amount to a value < s
```

Using these definitions, s in the given code gives you the prefix sum up to the current index i (P[i]). total builds the answer, and update simply adds P[i] to the BIT.

We have to repeat this method for all i, hence the for loop.

PS: It uses a data structure called a Binary Indexed Tree (http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=binaryIndexedTrees) for operations. If you aren't acquainted with it, I'd recommend that you check the link.

EDIT:
You are given a array S and a value X. You can split S into two disjoint subarrays such that L has all elements of S less than X, and H that has those that are greater than or equal to X.

```
A: All elements of L are less than all elements of H.
```

Any subsequence T of S will have some elements of L and some elements of H. Let's say it has p elements of L and q of H. When T is sorted to give T', all p elements of L appear before the q elements of H because of A.

```
Median being the central value is the value at location m = (p + q)/2
```

It is intuitive to think that having q >= p implies that the median lies in X, as a proof:
Values in locations [1..p] in T' belong to L. Therefore for the median to be in H, it's position m should be greater than p:

```
m > p
(p + q)/2 > p
p + q > 2p
q > p
B: q - p > 0
```

To computer q - p, I replace all elements in T' with -1 if they belong to L ( < X ) and +1 if they belong to H ( >= X)
T looks something like {-1, -1, -1... 1, 1, 1}
It has p times -1 and q times 1. Sum of T' will now give me:

```
Sum = p * (-1) + q * (1)
C: Sum = q - p
```

I can use this information to find the value in B.

All subsequences are of the form {A[i], A[i + 2], A[i + 3] ... A[j + 1]} since they are contiguous, To compute sum of A[i] to A[j + 1], I can compute the prefix sum of A[i] with P[i] = A[1] + A[2] + .. A[i - 1]
Sum of subsequence from A[i] to A[j] then can be computed as P[j] - P[i] (j is greater of j and i)
With C and B in mind, we conclude:

```
Sum = P[j] - P[i] = q - p  (q - p > 0)
P[j] - P[i] > 0
P[j] > P[i]
```

j > i and P[j] > P[i] for each solution that gives you a median >= X

In summary:

1. Replace all A[i] with -1 if they are less than X and -1 otherwise
2. Computer prefix sums of A[i]
3. For each pair (i, P[i]), count pairs which lie to its lower left quadrant.

Comment: Why is counting the number of subarrays with nonnegative sums equivalent to the problem of finding the number of points in the lower-left quadrant of each point in the plane?

Comment: Also, in this line `C[s] = Number of Prefix Sums of array A[1..(i - 1)] that amount to s` why are you taking the prefix sum?

Comment: @user2612743 I've added the answer to the first question to the post. As for the second part, P denotes prefix sum array; I'm using C to count the number of times s appears in P.

Comment: Sorry to bump this after a long time, but in your answer you said that update(p) adds P[i] to the binary indexed tree? However, in the solution page it stated that update(p) increments A[p] where A is the implicit array encoded in the BIT. Are these two operations the same thing or am I missing something?

Comment: @user2612743 The BIT stores prefix sums of C. Once you calculate P[i], its effect on C[P[i]] is additiin of 1 because C stores the number of times the value of P[i] occurs. Poor choice of wording on my part